# Using add_filter - Based on category and role

Tags: php, wordpress-theming, wordpress

I can successfully use 'add_filter' to change the post status to 'pending' when posts are published.

```
function publish_as_pending( $data , $postarr ) {  

  $data['post_status'] = 'pending';   

  return $data;

}

add_filter('wp_insert_post_data' , 'publish_as_pending' , '99', 2);
```

How can I change this to only filter when;

a) The post category ID is 1

b) The user publishing is role 'contributor'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> Add This Function on Function.php
> ```

```
function filter_handler( $data , $postarr ){
    if($postarr['post_category']):
        foreach( $postarr['post_category'] as $category_id ) {
             if ($category_id ==1 || current_user_can('contributor')){
                 $data['post_status'] = 'pending';   
                 return $data;
             }
        }
    endif;    
    return $data;

}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'filter_handler', '99', 2 );
```

[moreinfo to Go.](http://cmsblogheart.wordpress.com/2014/01/13/using-add_filter-change-post-status/)

Comment: If I swap the OR for AND then this should be perfect. Thank You!